# Can't save websphere server configuration using administration console

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I'm trying to save changes to websphere configuration using its administration console, but I get the following error message:

```
SystemErr     R javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.WorkSpaceException: 
WKSP0008E RepositoryException while checking the state of cells/TCNode01Cell/audit.xml in the 
master repository --com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.WorkSpaceException: 
WKSP0016E Error get digest for cells/TCNode01Cell/audit.xml.workspace_save
 --java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ACED2005
```

I checked that the audit.xml.workspace_save exists and it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell just from that message what's going on.  See if SystemOut.log contains more clues (that's in your `/<was_home>/profiles/<profile_name>/logs/<server_name>` directory).  The error may also have created ffdc files with more clues.

Also make sure there is still free space, since a disk full condition can sometimes cause odd errors that otherwise wouldn't hint the disk is full.